Would a Starlink mini placed inside a plane's cabin be able to get an Internet connection?
I wonder the following: Would a Starlink mini placed inside a plane's cabin be able to get an Internet connection? I am interested in both private and commercial planes.

Nope!
Starlink units require a clear view of the sky, and preferably a large portion of the sky. The metal body of the aircraft will block the signal. Specifically, Starlink uses Ku-band frequencies between 12 and 18 GHz and any aluminum sheet which is thicker than about 10 micrometers (µm) will essentially completely attenuate (block) the signal--the skin of planes is often many millimeters of aluminum thick.
Theoretically, if you placed it directly against a window, you might get lucky and occasionally get bursts of extremely poor connectivity due to the bad angle and limited FOV, but if you really want to fit a Starlink onto a private or commercial plane, you will need to install the unit in such a way that it is outside of the main body of the aircraft.
This is usually done with a "radome", also called "satcom" or "hump" antennas.
Here is an image of what this looks like on a real plane:

(image source)

Just to add: composite planes have a conductive mesh layer to protect against lightning strikes, but the hole spacing would have to be <1.6 mm to be a Faraday cage at 20 GHz

Does Starlink- or at least retail terminals- have any restrictions on the speed of movement to prevent them being used in drones? I'm considering the parallel with GPS here, which is normally speed-limited.

@MarkMorganLloyd You will not run into GPS-side restrictions unless your drone is an ICBM. Gov't restrictions stop consumer GPS units functioning if you are going over 1000 knots (1150 mph, 1850 kph) AND your altitude is above 60000 ft (~18000m). That said, Starlink has additional inbuilt software restrictions to prevent it being used "on the move", however, these are to get you to upgrade your plan to one which supports moving and not an inherent limitation of the system.

Also, as a fun side-note, the gov't GPS restrictions are completely pointless: your average electrical engineer or even HAM-Radio operator could easily build a GPS receiver which does not have the gov't firmware limitations, and so the idea that some foreign power building an ICBM would, in any way, be slowed down because they can't use COTS gps units is just laughable.

@Dragongeek it depends on the manufacturer. Some interpret COCOM limits as 'above permitted altitude AND above permitted speed', but some take a more restrictive 'or'. Occasionally you'll find a GPS chip that'll only implement one of the restrictions.

@mins Sure, but there are projects that, while not "cut and paste", make it easy for any technically adept person to build it from scratch like http://www.aholme.co.uk/GPS/Main.htm

@Dragongeek: Thanks for the link, really interesting project to study from, I wasn't aware of such discrete component implementation for the front-end. So you're right saying GPS limits are easy to circumvent.

I think the GPS limits probably meant something when it was created.  They're obviously obsolete by now.

@LorenPechtel I think that's a significant point: what an amateur or small company can make in 2024 is very different from what they could make when GPS came out. The project to which Dragongeek linked was circa 2013, I /might/ have seen older but wouldn't swear to it.

@MarkMorganLloyd Yeah, in the second paragraph of the article, the author states he was inspired by Matjaž Vidmar, who did a similar project "20 years ago" which would've put it in the 90's. Definitely something that required serious brainpower, and not something that an amateur can do without a postgraduate degree or similar.
